# How to create a Jenkins pipeline that builds a Docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Docker and Jenkins and I'm trying to create a Jenkins Pipeline that builds a Docker image.
I'm stuck when trying to build and keep receiving this error:

/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Docker-Pipeline@tmp/durable-a11b32f8/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found

1. I've installed ubuntu on a VM.
2. Installed docker.
3. Installed jenkins/jenkins from dockerhub.
4. I followed this tutorial for the rest:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z32yzy4TrKM&t=147s

I'm doing the exact same thing as him but it keeps failing.

```
Started by user admin
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/naorca/NodeApp.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start o

f Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Docker-Pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Clone repository)
[Pipeline] checkout
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/naorca/NodeApp.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/naorca/NodeApp.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/naorca/NodeApp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision b74538f2f34b6c28306fcca8119e215b87124e5e (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f b74538f2f34b6c28306fcca8119e215b87124e5e
Commit message: "Update Jenkinsfile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk b74538f2f34b6c28306fcca8119e215b87124e5e # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build image)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t naorca/nodeapp .
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Docker-Pipeline@tmp/durable-a11b32f8/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: It sounds like Docker isn't installed within your Jenkins Agent (FKA, "Jenkins Slave"). Based on the set-up you have described, I would hazard a guess that you are using the master as your build agent. That should be fine, but that will require Docker to be installed inside of the running `jenkins/jenkins` container. If Docker is in fact installed in the container, then it is possible that the path to the Docker executable's containing directory might be missing from the `PATH` environment variable, which would prevent your pipeline from calling it.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: You must have Docker within your Jenkins Agent.

Following the process you described above, I got Jenkins up and running using the latest [`jenkins/jenkins` image from Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins). After looking over the container's file system, I confirmed what I had speculated about in my comment on your question: Docker is not installed **within** the Jenkins container. Assuming you are using the Jenkins Master server as your Agent for the pipeline job, you have a couple options that come to mind:

1. Extend the existing docker container -- using something like `FROM jenkins/jenkins` inside of a new docker file -- to include your dependencies.
2. Bind your existing docker daemon from the host into the run-time of the Jenkins container.

While I am partial to the first solution, I found an implementation of the second solution on the Docker Forums: "[Using docker in a dockerized Jenkins container](https://forums.docker.com/t/using-docker-in-a-dockerized-jenkins-container/322)" I then gave that solution a try and can confirm that Docker is present for me in the Jenkins Master container after launching the Jenkins container with the following command:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v $(which docker):$(which docker) \
    -p 8000:8080 \
    -p 50000:50000 \
    jenkins/jenkins
```

I am not sure, but I would imagine there could be some negative security implications for the host of the Jenkins Master due to mounting its own Docker socket and Docker executable into the container; however, I would leave that up to someone more knowledgeable about Docker's internals to determine. Regardless, I can confirm that the solution above does work.

Comment: Thank you for this!!
Can you please guide me or direct me to a guide which describe how to configure a Jenkins Agent (FKA, "Jenkins Slave")? Does it needs to be on a different VM?
Really appreciate this !

Comment: Jenkins Agents can be added via the Nodes section. I believe the URI for that is `/computer/`, but you can also get there by clicking on the "Build Executor Status" in the left-hand menu. Then you can select "New Node" from the list of options. A Jenkins Master can act as its own agent, which is fine for single-user/single-team Jenkins servers; however, if you intend to make your Jenkins server available to multiple users/teams, then you should create isolated agents. I would recommend reading [Distributed Builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) on the Jenkins Wiki.